# IntelliJ keeps reverting my changes?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle/Groovy project that I am using IntelliJ with:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1
Build #IU-172.3544.35, built on July 31, 2017
Subscription is active until April 3, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
```

This issue just started when I tried editing a file that was in one of the  folders marked as "Exclude" (dark orange folder icon).  The problem never happens with files in one of the "Source" folders.  While editing it, I get a "File Cache Conflict" and IntelliJ offers me the option to Reload/Ignore/View Diffs.  If I make a change and switch away from the Tab with the source file, IntelliJ just reverts it silently and when I return to the Tab the file has gone back to the pre-edited state.

If it matters, the file I'm editing that has this problem is common.gradle in the Excluded "build" folder tree.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you keep the project files on the local drive?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, and then push to GitHub as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the file is not being automatically generated? In that case it's not IntelliJ IDEA "reverting" your changes, but simply reloading the file because it detected changes that happened outside of its control (or as a side effect of an operation actually triggered by the IDE). The fact that IntelliJ IDEA is warning you that the file has changed indicates that it is *not* IntelliJ IDEA who's making those changes. And that would also be a good reason to keep that directory as excluded and *not* modify that file manually.

Comment: @EnricoMCrisostom - I don't know.  I wondered that myself, but I don't know how to figure that out.  Any tips?

Comment: @RobertOschler Provided I have no idea about how your project works, you may close the IDE, purge the excluded directory (if you can, or move it elsewhere), and perform the operations you were performing when the problem happened, but this time from outside the IDE. If the file get recreated, now you know that it's not IntelliJ IDEA's fault.

Comment: @EnricoMCrisostom - Good idea for a test.  I'll try that.

Comment: How did your search go?

Comment: thank you a lot, i didn't realize that my file is auto generated.